# Discord Example cog bot error

Tags: discord, discord.py

İ'm Getting this error i try use example bot some user but getting this error when type help

AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'guild'

Please help also getting this error
also so much error getting more on hastebin https://hastebin.com/ipalesajus.sql

Comment: Solved this: `Failed to load extension cogs.simple.`?

Comment: yes it gives failed

Comment: This probably causes the other problems...

Comment: How i can solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Message](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=Message#message) documentation.

Based on the documentation stated, there is no `guild` property in `Message`. I believe what you are looking for is the `server` property instead.
(Instead of `Message.guild`, use `Message.server`)

Note that it might return a `None` if the message was in a DM, etc.

Based on that, the example bot is probably suited for older versions of Discord.py instead. You might have to make a few edits to the bot to match up with the newest version.

Also, make sure that you downloaded the library/API the example bot used too.

Comment: This must be a very old API, as about a year ago **Discord** officially changed its `server`s in their API to `guild`s...